# WHERE NOT EXISTS doesn't work with trailing whitespace

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am running the command `SELECT distinct winner FROM history WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM players WHERE players.name = history.winner)`

It seems to fail if `history.winner` is something like "Test " (notice trailing space) and players.name already has "Test"

I had the same issue for case insensitive so I made both field collation be latin1_general_cs, if that plays any role. I think solution may result in using the BINARY keyword but doing

`SELECT distinct BINARY winner FROM history WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM players WHERE BINARY players.name = history.winner)` make the query very very slow (so slow that I quit after 1 minute).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**Trim()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to accomplish this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT h.winner 
FROM history h
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM players p  
  WHERE Trim(p.name) = Trim(h.winner)
)
```

Comment: Seems to suffer from the same slowness as BINARY, I assume because it has to run trim() a lot of times.

Comment: Yes, you could alleviate this by changing the structure of your database.  Use primary and foreign keys to reference a `name` and not the actual `name`/`winner`.

Comment: That is actually what I am trying to do, I have no knowledge of the player names before hand so it scans the history and inserts them into player table. Then I have a modified history which uses the player.id instead of a player.name - Seems it may be easier to set name as UNIQUE key and then do INSERT IGNORE and just bruteforce INSERT all "winners" into players table

Comment: You could also alleviate having to use the `Trim()` function all of the time by updating the `history` and `players` tables beforehand.  Something like `UPDATE players SET name = Trim(name)` and `UPDATE history SET winner = Trim(winner)`.  Then you wouldn't need to use `Trim()` in your `SELECT` statement above.

Comment: The trailing spaces are important, "Test      " "Test" and "Test  " should be all unique. It seems it has something to do with how mysql is inserting, because it says `#1062 - Duplicate entry 'Test ' for key 'name' ` and yet "Test " doesn't exist, but "Test" does.

Comment: Is `name` defined as `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`?  `VARCHAR` should preserved trailing white spaces.  Where `CHAR` does not.

Comment: It is a VARCHAR. I just now read the documentation and I think the issue arises from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html where it starts out: 'All MySQL collations are of type PADSPACE.' - So while it will store with trailing spaces (I use MYSQL 5.1.72) it will not correctly do a comparison. Seemingly the "duplicate" finding must use this type of search. I will convert to blob and try

Answer (score 0):

The mysql `TRIM()` function will strip leading and trailing whitespaces from a particular field.

```
SELECT distinct winner FROM history WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM players WHERE players.name = TRIM(history.winner))
```

If you only want to trim trailing spaces you can use `RTRIM()` instead.

[Relevant Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim)